# AngularJS - IE8 html template

Tags: angularjs

Does anyone know of a boilerplate template for using AngularJS in IE8. In the docs there is a whole section devoted to getting Angular working with IE8 and it seems the steps required are quite specific, but so far I have had little success with commands like ng-include

If the steps are quite specific then I assume someone has some boilerplate code somewhere  that is confirmed to work with IE8, it would be appreciated if that could be shared. At least if it does not work then you at least know you have started from known baseline and would make it easier to isolate problems.

Comment: That's not how it works here. Rather, show what YOU tried, tell us what didn't work, so that we can help you fixing it.

Answer (score 4):

I have created 2 production applications using AngularJS that run in IE8 perfectly fine with just a few javascript 'fixes'.

First, if the developer console is not open the console.log statements will fail. I fixed it with the following js snippet on the initial page that spawns the angular app:

```
 // Avoid `console` errors in browsers that lack a console.
            (function() {
                var method;
                var noop = function () {};
                var methods = [
                    'assert', 'clear', 'count', 'debug', 'dir', 'dirxml', 'error',
                    'exception', 'group', 'groupCollapsed', 'groupEnd', 'info', 'log',
                    'markTimeline', 'profile', 'profileEnd', 'table', 'time', 'timeEnd',
                    'timeStamp', 'trace', 'warn'
                ];
                var length = methods.length;
                var console = (window.console = window.console || {});

                while (length--) {
                    method = methods[length];

                    // Only stub undefined methods.
                    if (!console[method]) {
                        console[method] = noop;
                    }
                }
            }());
```

Second, I use toISOString for converting date time stamps. In IE, that function is not implemented so I am using this snippet:

```
 /*IE8 toISOString hack */
            if (!Date.prototype.toISOString) {
                Date.prototype.toISOString = function() {
                    function pad(n) { return n < 10 ? '0' + n : n }
                    return this.getUTCFullYear() + '-'
                        + pad(this.getUTCMonth() + 1) + '-'
                        + pad(this.getUTCDate()) + 'T'
                        + pad(this.getUTCHours()) + ':'
                        + pad(this.getUTCMinutes()) + ':'
                        + pad(this.getUTCSeconds()) + '.'
                        + pad(this.getUTCMilliseconds()) + 'Z';
                };
            }
```

Third, the forEach method is not supported in IE, so I am using this:

```
/*IE8 hack to support forEach */
            if (!Array.prototype.forEach) {
              Array.prototype.forEach = function(fn, scope) {
                for(var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; ++i) {
                  fn.call(scope, this[i], i, this);
                }
              }
            }
```

All of these code snippets were poached from StackOverflow answers and the work for me but YMMV.

I read through the angular IE8 documentation and I have not run into any of the situations described in the documentation. For directives, I use the format: `<div directive-name>` and everything works fine.

Comment: Install a javascript code validator like https://github.com/jshint/jshint and validate all your javascript files. The solution for me was to remove unnecessary comma's and add semicolons.

Answer (score 1):

Although the question should be more detailed, I can speak of what I have done in the past to manage IE8 code.

Instead of worrying about boilerplates and productivity killing procedures, I let yeoman handle all of this for me.

**http://yeoman.io/**

Yeoman is an opinionated assistant similar to Rail's rake that will help you build your app faster. Simply download the generator-angular and yeoman to get going.

**https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular**

If you don't want to integrate yeoman into your product, look at how yeoman lays down the IE8 boilerplate and copy it using a test app.

I hope this helps.