# Angular JS ui-router on Internet Explorer 8

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-8, angular-ui-router

Has anyone gotten the Angular JS ui-router quick-start to run in IE8? The quick start's here:
[ui-router quick-start](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router#quick-start)

It's working in chrome but not in IE8.

Thanks!

[Edit]
I have read the ie documentation under angular js but the fix provided doesn't seem to fix the issue (missing forEach method). The fix only addresses issues with angular js and not angular-ui-router.

The only thing that works is from an answer here: [AngularJS - IE8 html template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17953408/angularjs-ie8-html-template/17955643#17955643). The basically provides an implementation for forEach which is not supported in IE.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try building off of master? There was a pull request merged just after the last release (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/pull/392) that resolved some IE8 issues. Everything else should work fine AFAIK.

Comment: +1 : This definitely fixed the problem for me. I upgraded from **v0.0.1** (`ui.state`) to **v0.2.0** (`ui.router`) and fell foul of this little trap. I simply handed edited based on the [pull request change report](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/pull/392/files) and everything started working again.